# How to print a large block of text in bash without numerous echo lines?

Tags: bash, dry

Let's say I want to show the usage of my fancy bash script with the function:

```
function show_usage()
{
   echo "Auto generates a recipe for the day!"
   echo "my_script [-a][-b][-c]"
   echo 
   echo "To create a recipe use the three options to alter the type of recipe."
   echo "Options:"
   echo " -a: Add any extras/toppings"
   echo " -b: Allow experimental recipes (beta)"
   echo " -c: Cut out any waste."
   echo
   echo "Lorem ipsum natus sit voluptatem accusantium..."
}
```

You get the idea...
All those `echo`s start to get a bit tiresome and look messy.

Is there an approach for this in bash that doesn't use a bunch of echo lines?

Comment: [heredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/heredoc/info)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use bash heredoc.

For example:

```
cat << \
=========================================================================
Auto generates a recipe for the day!
my_script [-a][-b][-c]

To create a recipe use the three options to alter the type of recipe.
Options:
 -a: Add any extras/toppings
 -b: Allow experimental recipes (beta)
 -c: Cut out any waste.

Lorem ipsum natus sit voluptatem accusantium...
=========================================================================
```

The first & last lines act as beginning and end, they can be any string you like, but they have to be identical.

Comment: Look great! Can you add variables to that too?

Comment: @CodingFrog absolutely you can insert variables. Try replacing `my_script` with `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal "best" but here are three less verbose ways.

With `<<`:

```
function show_usage()
{
   cat <<EOD
Auto generates a recipe for the day!
my_script [-a][-b][-c]

To create a recipe use the three options to alter the type of recipe.
Options:
 -a: Add any extras/toppings
 -b: Allow experimental recipes (beta)
 -c: Cut out any waste.

Lorem ipsum natus sit voluptatem accusantium...
EOD
}
```

with tab-indented `<<` (needs real tabs - stackoverflow doesn't display them properly here):

```
function show_usage()
{
   cat <<-EOD
    Auto generates a recipe for the day! 
    my_script [-a][-b][-c] 

    To create a recipe use the three options to alter the type of recipe. 
    Options: 
     -a: Add any extras/toppings 
     -b: Allow experimental recipes (beta) 
     -c: Cut out any waste. 

    Lorem ipsum natus sit voluptatem accusantium... 
    EOD
}
```

As a single double-quoted string with embeded newlines:

```
function show_usage()
{
   echo "\
Auto generates a recipe for the day!
my_script [-a][-b][-c]

To create a recipe use the three options to alter the type of recipe.
Options:
 -a: Add any extras/toppings
 -b: Allow experimental recipes (beta)
 -c: Cut out any waste.

Lorem ipsum natus sit voluptatem accusantium..."
}
```